# Use of ILogger in Acumatica Dependency Injection

Tags: acumatica

In previous versions, I registered Serilog.ILogger in the container as follows:

```
        builder.Register(context => PXTrace.Logger).As<ILogger>();
```

So that I could inject it into types registered in the container:
[image]

In 22R2 this seems to have stopped working, but there is no error. When I call _logger.Information("test"); or _logger.Error() nothing is written to the trace. I know one can use Microsofts ILogger interface to inject into a graph, but how does one inject a non generic ILogger interface into an object that is not necessarily tied to a graph?

Thanks

Comment: How do you create the instance of that object? You can try to create it using the Container itself, that should resolve the injection part

Comment: I create it using the container, and the container passes an ILogger object in and I call the _logger.Information("Test info"), but the text "Test Info" is not making it to the trace screen.

Comment: It almost feels like they are actually using `PXTrace._logger` and not `PXTrace.Logger` and that is what actually causes the issue for you. The problem is that the _logger and the class assigned to it are internal and I guess you can't use them in your library

Comment: Strange, I pretty explicitly register PXTrace.Logger in the builder as shown above, annoying.